# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pytabix, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install `pytabix` (https://github.com/slowkow/pytabix/tree/master) on WSL1 ubuntu:
`python -m pip install pytabix`

I've got this message.
How to fix this?

```
Collecting pytabix
  Using cached pytabix-0.1.tar.gz (45 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pytabix
  Building wheel for pytabix (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pytabix (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [147 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/test
      copying test/test.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/test
      copying test/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/test
      copying test/example.gtf.gz -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/test
      copying test/example.gtf.gz.tbi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/test
      running build_ext
      building 'tabix' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src
      /home/dan/miniconda3/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/include -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/include -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_USE_KNETFILE=1 -Isrc -I/home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include/python3.9 -c src/bgzf.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/bgzf.o
      src/bgzf.c: In function 'bgzf_flush':
      src/bgzf.c:398:61: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'size_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
        398 |   if (fwrite(fp->compressed_block, 1, block_length, fp->fp) != block_length) {
            |                                                             ^~
      src/bgzf.c: In function 'bgzf_close':
      src/bgzf.c:435:11: warning: variable 'count' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
        435 |  int ret, count, block_length;
            |           ^~~~~
      /home/dan/miniconda3/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/include -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/include -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_USE_KNETFILE=1 -Isrc -I/home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include/python3.9 -c src/bgzip.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/bgzip.o
      /home/dan/miniconda3/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/include -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/include -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_USE_KNETFILE=1 -Isrc -I/home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include/python3.9 -c src/index.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/index.o
      In file included from src/index.c:5:
      src/index.c: In function 'ks_sample_offt':
      src/ksort.h:276:19: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'size_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        276 |             if (k != n - pop - 1) tmp = a[k], a[k] = a[n-pop-1], a[n-pop-1] = tmp; \
            |                   ^~
      src/index.c:22:1: note: in expansion of macro 'KSORT_INIT'
         22 | KSORT_INIT(offt, pair64_t, pair64_lt)
            | ^~~~~~~~~~
      src/index.c: In function 'merge_chunks':
      src/index.c:267:18: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'uint32_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        267 |    for (l = 1; l < p->n; ++l) {
            |                  ^
      src/index.c: In function 'ti_index_core':
      src/index.c:310:14: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'uint64_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} and 'int32_t' {aka 'int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        310 |   if (lineno <= idx->conf.line_skip || str->s[0] == idx->conf.meta_char) {
            |              ^~
      src/index.c:334:16: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'uint32_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        334 |   if (intv.bin != last_bin) { // then possibly write the binning index
            |                ^~
      src/index.c:342:21: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int64_t' {aka 'long int'} and 'uint64_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        342 |   if (bgzf_tell(fp) <= last_off) {
            |                     ^~
      src/index.c: In function 'ti_index_save':
      src/index.c:417:17: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int32_t' {aka 'int'} and 'khint_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        417 |   for (i = 0; i < kh_size(idx->tname); ++i)
            |                 ^
      src/index.c:421:17: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int32_t' {aka 'int'} and 'khint_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        421 |   for (i = 0; i < kh_size(idx->tname); ++i)
            |                 ^
      src/index.c:441:25: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'uint32_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        441 |      for (x = 0; (int)x < p->n; ++x) {
            |                         ^
      src/index.c:446:25: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'uint32_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        446 |      for (x = 0; (int)x < p->n; ++x) {
            |                         ^
      src/index.c: In function 'ti_index_load_core':
      src/index.c:546:19: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'uint32_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        546 |     for (x = 0; x < p->n; ++x) {
            |                   ^
      src/index.c: In function 'reg2bins':
      src/index.c:750:31: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'uint32_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        750 |  for (k =    1 + (beg>>26); k <=    1 + (end>>26); ++k) list[i++] = k;
            |                               ^~
      src/index.c:751:31: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'uint32_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        751 |  for (k =    9 + (beg>>23); k <=    9 + (end>>23); ++k) list[i++] = k;
            |                               ^~
      src/index.c:752:31: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'uint32_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        752 |  for (k =   73 + (beg>>20); k <=   73 + (end>>20); ++k) list[i++] = k;
            |                               ^~
      src/index.c:753:31: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'uint32_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        753 |  for (k =  585 + (beg>>17); k <=  585 + (end>>17); ++k) list[i++] = k;
            |                               ^~
      src/index.c:754:31: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'uint32_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        754 |  for (k = 4681 + (beg>>14); k <= 4681 + (end>>14); ++k) list[i++] = k;
            |                               ^~
      src/index.c: In function 'ti_iter_query':
      src/index.c:808:18: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'uint32_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
        808 |    for (j = 0; j < p->n; ++j)
            |                  ^
      /home/dan/miniconda3/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/include -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/include -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_USE_KNETFILE=1 -Isrc -I/home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include/python3.9 -c src/knetfile.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/knetfile.o
      /home/dan/miniconda3/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/include -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/include -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_USE_KNETFILE=1 -Isrc -I/home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include/python3.9 -c src/kstring.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/kstring.o
      src/kstring.c: In function 'ksprintf':
      src/kstring.c:15:12: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'size_t' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-Wsign-compare]
         15 |  if (l + 1 > s->m - s->l) {
            |            ^
      /home/dan/miniconda3/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/include -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/include -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_USE_KNETFILE=1 -Isrc -I/home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/include/python3.9 -c src/tabixmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/tabixmodule.o
      /home/dan/miniconda3/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -shared -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-rpath,/home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/lib -L/home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/lib -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-rpath,/home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/lib -L/home/dan/miniconda3/envs/r-reticulate/lib -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-rpath,/home/dan/miniconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dan/miniconda3/lib -L/home/dan/miniconda3/lib -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/include -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/dan/miniconda3/include build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/bgzf.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/bgzip.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/index.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/knetfile.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/kstring.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/tabixmodule.o -lz -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/tabix.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
      installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
      running install
      running install_lib
      creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64
      creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
      copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/tabix.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
      creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/test
      copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/test/example.gtf.gz -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/test
      copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/test/example.gtf.gz.tbi -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/test
      copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/test/test.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/test
      copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/test/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/test
      running install_egg_info
      running egg_info
      writing pytabix.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to pytabix.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to pytabix.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'pytabix.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'pytabix.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      Copying pytabix.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/pytabix-0.1-py3.8.egg-info
      running install_scripts
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/dan/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/dan/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/dan/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-l79aqrqu/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 416, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-l79aqrqu/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 401, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-l79aqrqu/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-l79aqrqu/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 45, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-l79aqrqu/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-l79aqrqu/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-l79aqrqu/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-l79aqrqu/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-l79aqrqu/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-l79aqrqu/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-l79aqrqu/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 380, in run
          impl_tag, abi_tag, plat_tag = self.get_tag()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-l79aqrqu/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 329, in get_tag
          assert (
      AssertionError: would build wheel with unsupported tag ('cp38', 'cp39', 'linux_x86_64')
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pytabix
Failed to build pytabix
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pytabix, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0):

I work around to successfully install `pytabix` by `conda`

```
(base) dan@DESKTOP-0TJ97T7:~$ conda install -c bioconda pytabix
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/dan/miniconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - pytabix


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    pytabix-0.1                |   py38h8e3bb3f_1          50 KB  bioconda
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:          50 KB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  pytabix            bioconda/linux-64::pytabix-0.1-py38h8e3bb3f_1


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

```
(base) dan@DESKTOP-0TJ97T7:~$ python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tabix
>>>
```